# hyperledger fabric running speed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We know that there exists several stage in Fabric such as endorsement, ordering and endorsement validation. I have a question: when you start to execute query or invoke command, how to calculate the running time for every stage?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you I can think of is by parsing and analysis of logs.
Other wise, you can try any golang profiler to profile and calculate the time taken at each stage.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. And I still have some question: It means we use docker log to parse and analyse the logs?? I am not familiar to golang profiler, how to use it??